# Hide GUI when target window not active or minimized

Tags: autohotkey

My code does the following:

- When a google.com window becomes active, it will show you a simple GUI.
- Then, if you switch to another tab, the GUI will be hidden.[1]

[1]. Note, that it works as well for the tabs opened in another browser window. For example, you may have 2 browser windows opened - the first window with `google.com` and `apple.com`, and the second window with `amazon.com`. You can click `apple.com` tab as well as `amazon.com` tab, and in both cases the GUI will be hidden. Then, if you click `google.com` tab, the GUI will be shown again.

The problem is, that I cannot figure out how to force the GUI to be hidden when the window (which contains `google.com` tab) is minimized. (And also, I cannot get rid of feeling that there are another errors, that are not visible while testing, but actually exist).

To sum this up, what I want is this:

> As soon as a non-google window or tab is clicked/activated (excluding
>   the AHK Gui) the Gui should be hidden and as soon as any
>   google-window/tab is clicked/activated the Gui should be shown.

Here is my code:

```
#Persistent
SetTimer, Show_Gui, 300
Return

Show_Gui:
IfWinNotActive, foo
IfWinNotActive, Google
{
    Gui, Destroy
    Return
}
; Otherwise:
SetTimer, Show_Gui, Off
Gui, Add, Button, w200 h25 gTest1, button 1
Gui, Add, Button, w200 h25 gTest2, button 2
Gui, Show,, foo
WinWaitNotActive, foo
WinWaitNotActive, Google
SetTimer, Show_Gui, On
Return

Test1:
; do something
Return

Test2:
; do something
Return
```

---

Edit. Here is the code as discussed in comments to Forivin's post. It is not part of the actual question.

```
#Persistent

Gui, Add, Button, w200 h25 gTest1, button 1
Gui, Add, Button, w200 h25 gTest2, button 2

GroupAdd, myGroup, Google
GroupAdd, myGroup, foo

WinWaitActive, Google
Gui, Show,, foo
SetTimer, Gui_Visibility_Handler, 300
Return

Gui_Visibility_Handler:
    WinGet, googleWinState, MinMax, Google
    If (googleWinState = -1 || !WinExist("Google")) ;if window minimized or not existent
    {
        Gui, Hide
        If (googleWinState = -1) ;workaround for a bug where windows thinks
            Send, !{Esc}         ;that the minimized window is active
        WinWaitActive, Google
        Gui, Show
        Return
    }
    IfWinActive, Google
    {
        Gui, Show
        Return
    }
    IfWinNotActive, ahk_group MyGroup
    {
        Gui, Hide
        Return
    }
Return

Test1:
;do something
Return

Test2:
;do something
Return
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**EDIT**:
Here is the new code as discussed in the comments:

```
#Persistent

Gui, Add, Button, w200 h25 gTest1, button 1
Gui, Add, Button, w200 h25 gTest2, button 2
Gui, +hwndAhkGui

lastActive := WinExist("A")

SetTimer, Active_Window_Memory
SetTimer, Gui_Visibility_Handler, 300

Return

Gui_Visibility_Handler:
    WinGet, googleWinState, MinMax, Google
    If (googleWinState != -1 && IsGoogleWindow(currentActive)) ;if google is not minimized and: (google is active or: (ahk gui is active and google was active before that))
    {
        Gui, Show
    }
    Else If (currentActive = AhkGui && IsGoogleWindow(lastActive))
    {
        ;No need to do anything
    }
    Else
    {
        Gui, Hide
    }
Return

IsGoogleWindow(hWnd) {
    WinGetTitle, title, ahk_id %hWnd%
    If (InStr(title, " - Google Chrome"))
    {
        title := RegExReplace(title, " - Google Chrome$", "") ;remove the " - Google Chrome" from the title
    } 

    If (InStr(title, "Google"))
    {
        Return True
    }

    Return False
}

Active_Window_Memory:
    currentActive := WinExist("A")
    WinWaitNotActive, ahk_id %currentActive%
    lastActive := currentActive
Return

Test1:
; do something
Return

Test2:
; do something
Return
```

Comment: Thanks, it's working well, except it doesn't hide GUI when I click tab on another browser window. I created image with 4 screenshots to explain: http://imgur.com/vfPSbqL

Comment: Okay, let me try to summarize what I understand: As soon as a non-google window or tab is clicked/activated (excluding the AHK Gui) you want the Gui to be hidden and as soon as any google-window/tab is clicked/activated you want the Gui to be shown. Is that correct?

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I want.

Comment: Okay, I'll try to make that happen later this day.

Comment: Alright, I added the new code to the comments. Tell me if it works. :)

Comment: To be honest, the new code doesn't work properly. The GUI is shown no matter what tabs I'm clicking. Yesterday night I already have modified your second code, and in my tests it was working well, but I was afraid, that it is not correct (because I'm newbie in AHK). I have added this modification to my post. Be sure, I will mark your post as answer anyway. We may extend this discussion in chat, tell me if my modifcation of your code looks good or no)

Comment: I tested the script on two different computers with Firefox and IE. Even with both running at the same time and it does exactly what I wrote in the second comment. Are you sure you ran the correct version? And that only one script was running etc? EDIT: I just ran your edited code and what it does for me is quickly switching between the AHK Gui and the browser window again and again.. That can't be what you wanted? Is your AHK up2date? Also, what version of Windows are you on?

Comment: I'm using Win7 32bit, Ultimate, AHK ver was 1.1.14.03, also tested on updated to 1.1.22.09, with no difference. Also, today I tested your 3rd script in Firefox (current release, 43.0.4), and in FF your 3rd script works like it should. However, in Chrome it is buggy. I have not any other scripts running, and also, it was fresh PC restart, with all other software disabled, including antivirus. I have marked your post as answer, because it's bring enough light to the problem and there was a lot of help, for which I'm grateful. In my case, the problem actually lighted and resolved fairly enough!

Comment: Okay the mistake is now pretty obvious to me. "Google Chrome" always has the word "Google" in its title, thus the script will always think that all tabs in Chrome are Google tabs. I think I can fix that though.

Comment: Okay I edited the script again. And now it works on IE, Firefox and Chrome.

Comment: Yes, that's working fine for me too, great! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

```
#Persistent
SetTitleMatchMode, 2

GroupAdd, Amazon_Apple_Group, Amazon.com ahk_exe firefox.exe
GroupAdd, Amazon_Apple_Group, Amazon.com ahk_exe chrome.exe
GroupAdd, Amazon_Apple_Group, Apple - Mozilla Firefox ahk_exe firefox.exe
GroupAdd, Amazon_Apple_Group, Apple - Google Chrome ahk_exe chrome.exe

Gui, Add, Button, w200 h25 gTest1, button 1
Gui, Add, Button, w200 h25 gTest2, button 2
SetTimer, Show_Gui, 300
Return


Show_Gui:
IfWinActive, ahk_group Amazon_Apple_Group
{
SetTimer, Show_Gui, Off
Gui, Show, NoActivate, foo
WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, On, foo ahk_class AutoHotkeyGUI
WinWaitNotActive, ahk_group Amazon_Apple_Group
Sleep, 50
Gui, Cancel
SetTimer, Show_Gui, On
}
Return


Test1:
Gui, Submit
; do sth
Return

Test2:
Gui, Submit
; do sth
return
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GroupAdd.htm

"If a timer is disabled while its subroutine is currently running, that subroutine will continue until it completes."
https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/SetTimer.htm#Remarks

"SetTimer, Show_Gui, Off" turns the timer off until the following subroutine

```
Gui, Show, NoActivate, foo
WinSet, AlwaysOnTop, On, foo ahk_class AutoHotkeyGUI
WinWaitNotActive, ahk_group Amazon_Apple_Group
Sleep, 50
Gui, Cancel
SetTimer, Show_Gui, On
```

completes.

The subroutine automatically turns the timer on after completion.

Comment: I checked your answer later, but it also very good, thanks. Can you explain, why we need to set `SetTimer, Show_Gui, Off` and `SetTimer, Show_Gui, On`?

Comment: See the comments added.

Comment: Thanks, I have read the SetTimer docs. May be I was not clear enough, sorry. I have asked why we need to `SetTimer` Off and On, while the script is working well even if we remove these two lines? On my unprofessional view, these two lines are seems to be redundant.

Comment: For a simple standalone script without any further complications like this this matter is of little importance. (In this case you can use a loop instead of the timer). ...